# Sudden removal of "@angular folder from the node modules "as soon as I install ionic app scripts

Tags: angularjs, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HGBQ.png)[image]

First we used it on some other machines but as soon as I changed the machine with same code and same ionic version, npm version etc, It shows me the error:

```
failed to load index.html file
```

As soon as I install ionic app scripts.

Comment: Hi Shubham, please don't post images, but cut and paste the error as code (text) into your question

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But your question still need additional information to be solvable.

Comment: Thanks @Bsquare. I have provided more details in the links.please goo through it and it will be great help if you guide me along.